# What is ptr_munge in the apple argument to main?

Tags: c, macos

I was recently looking into additional arguments to main and I found that apart from argc, argv and envp on macOS there is also an extra char **apple option.

Obviously the first thing I did was quickly loop over it:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp, char ** apple)
{
    puts("-----------------Apple-----------------");
    for(char **a = apple; *a != 0; a++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and see what was in there which was:

```
-----------------Apple-----------------
executable_path=bin/apple



ptr_munge=
main_stack=
executable_file=0x1901000004,0x2ea3d0
dyld_file=0x1901000004,0xab575
```

Assuming they're not totally misleading names I can guess what the rest of them are but I was a bit stumped by `ptr_munge` - what is that and what can be done with it? (Also what's all the extra whitespace there for?)

EDIT:

OK I found this file: [kern_exec.c](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c) which contains this:

```
/*
 * libplatform needs a random pointer-obfuscation value when it is initialized.
 */
#define PTR_MUNGE_VALUES 1
#define PTR_MUNGE_KEY "ptr_munge="
...
/*
* Supply libpthread & libplatform with a random value to use for pointer
* obfuscation.
*/
error = exec_add_entropy_key(imgp, PTR_MUNGE_KEY, PTR_MUNGE_VALUES, FALSE);
if (error) {
    goto bad;
}
imgp->ip_applec++;
```

So I am still pretty unsure what that means in context (there's nothing in my one) but I can follow this thread.

Comment: What code produces this output?

Comment: From the name, my guess is that it's related to whatever the Mac OS equivalent of ASLR is.

Comment: The reason that it's empty and that there are empty strings in the array is that libplatform, Libc, and libSystem erase entries after they consume them during initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that it's used to obfuscate the register values stored in `jmp_buf` by `_setjmp()` (and then to restore them in `_longjmp()`). It's presumably a security/data-privacy feature. It seems to have been introduced with 10.14. It isn't in the 10.13.x code.

See the code [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libplatform/libplatform-177.200.16/src/setjmp/x86_64/_setjmp.s.auto.html), for example:

```
LEAF(__setjmp, 0)
    // %rdi is a jmp_buf (struct sigcontext *)

    // now build sigcontext
    movq    %rbx, JB_RBX(%rdi)
    movq    %rbp, %rax
    _OS_PTR_MUNGE(%rax)
    movq    %rax, JB_RBP(%rdi)
    movq    %r12, JB_R12(%rdi)
    movq    %r13, JB_R13(%rdi)
    movq    %r14, JB_R14(%rdi)
    movq    %r15, JB_R15(%rdi)

    // RIP is set to the frame return address value
    movq    (%rsp), %rax
    _OS_PTR_MUNGE(%rax)
    movq    %rax, JB_RIP(%rdi)
    // RSP is set to the frame return address plus 8
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rax
    _OS_PTR_MUNGE(%rax)
    movq    %rax, JB_RSP(%rdi)

    // save fp control word
    fnstcw  JB_FPCONTROL(%rdi)

    // save MXCSR
    stmxcsr JB_MXCSR(%rdi)

    // return 0
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```